# Having a div appear on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot make the selected `div` appear and disappear on button press.

```
<button id="showButton" type="button">Show More</button>

<div id="container">
    <div id="fourthArticle">
        <img class="row1pic" id="pic4" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
       <p>
       <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span>
       this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
       </p>
    </div>

    <div id="fifthArticle">
        <img class="row1pic" id="pic5" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
       <p>
       <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span>   
       this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
       </p>
    </div>

    <div id="sixthArticle">
        <img class="row1pic" id="pic6" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
       <p>
       <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span> 
       this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
       </p>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#showButton').click(function () {
    $('#container').toggleClass('hidden');  
}

</script>
```

when I press the button, nothing happens. I tried putting an `alert` in the `.click` function, and that failed too. So I assume something is wrong with that, but from what I know, I have no idea what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: You're missing a closing thing or two.

Comment: A bit of general advice: as with any environment, use the debugging tools that are available. In this case, the "developer tools" provided by your browser would have pointed out the syntax error (missing close paren) in your click handler assignment, saving you at least some forehead-smacking. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your container div was not closed properly with a closing tag `</div>`.
2. Your event handler was not closed properly.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#showButton').click(function() {
    $('#container').toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showButton" type="button">Show More</button>

<div id="container">
  <div id="fourthArticle">
    <img class="row1pic" id="pic4" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
    <p>
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span>
      this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="fifthArticle">
    <img class="row1pic" id="pic5" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
    <p>
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span> this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="sixthArticle">
    <img class="row1pic" id="pic6" src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Shub-Niggurath-Rampage.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
    <p>
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is a third article</span> this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Obviously new, so still getting used to syntax. Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Try using valid Jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/bv5fLrth/18/

You were missing this: `);`

From the end of this:

```
$('#showButton').click(function () {
    $('#container').toggleClass('hidden');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your CSS for the class hidden? Have you tried adding display none CSS to container like so...

```
#container {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in your script use slideToggle like so but make sure your document ready function is there and the jquery syntax is correct...

```
$(function() {
  $('#showButton').click(function() {
    $('#container').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#main').toggleClass('hidden');  
});

<button id="btn">Change Mode</button>
<div id="main">
    <div>
        div One
    </div>
    <div>
        div two
    </div>
    <div>
        div three
    </div>
</div>
```